# iOS: Pushing views down when new

Tags: ios, user-interface

What is a good way of pushing a content box down when another box is being added to the view? When the another box is being taken away from the view, what is a good way of pushing the content box back up to the top of the page?

EDIT: Are there any examples of this anywhere?

Comment: probably should be done with a UIScrollView.

Comment: I believe auto layout can be a good way

Comment: How would this be done using auto layout?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right you can use animations to do what you are after...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:seconds animations:^ {
    //animation code here
    /*so eg: box1.frame = CGrectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
    then box1 will move and shape animating by itself for however 
    many seconds you specify until it is at it's given position 
    (0,0) and a size of 50 points wide and 50 points high */
}
```